# Time in HeadlessWorkspace

Tags: java, time, netlogo

I am using the headless. HeadlessWorkspace library of netlogo for JAVA and simulating a problem, it happens that I have 2 problems:

1. sometimes can not find the file "second.out"
2. when I do a simulation it takes a long time (or never ends), I want to know how long it has been trying to perform the simulation, so that exceeded that time discard the possible solution:

```
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;

public static void simulateNetLogo(){
        HeadlessWorkspace workspace =HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance() ;
        workspace.
        try {
            workspace.open("escape4.nlogo");
            workspace.command("reset-ticks");
            workspace.command("load-fixed-plan-file");
            workspace.command("load-fixed-door-file");
            workspace.command("generate-population");
            workspace.command("repeat 200 [go]");
            System.out.print(".");
            workspace.dispose();    
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR DESCONOCIDO EN EJECUION DE NETLOGO :(");
        }
    }
```

Comment: we'll need more context on the “second.out” problem — you've given us nothing to go on

Comment: sorry for that, when netlogo performs a simulation its output is a file called "second.out" (it is the tick mumer of the solution) I save this time and I do the process N times, but sometimes it fails and Neatbens tells me "second.out not found" .
The problem is one of turtle and patches

Comment: okay, but if you don't show us any actual code involving "second.out", I don't see how we can help you debug that code.

Comment: also I just noticed that one line of your code is just `workspace.` by itself — that doesn't even compile. is this your real code?